# How to change current-directory with emacsclient?

Tags: shell, emacsclient

I am trying to change the default directory using `emacsclient`, but it isn't working as I had hoped.

```
$ cd
$ emacsclient -e '(emacs-version)'
"GNU Emacs 28.0.50 (build 1, x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.22.30, cairo version 1.15.10)\n of 2020-02-19"
$ emacsclient -e '(setq default-directory "/home/joe/system-test/auth/")'
"/home/joe/system-test/auth/"
```

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `describe-variable` <kbd>RET</kbd> `default-directory` <kbd>RET</kbd>

> default-directory is a variable defined in ‘C source code’.
>   Its value is "/home/joe/"
>   Local in buffer *shell*; global value is nil

Comment: @Tobias, yep, this works for me.

Comment: Okay then we got the culprit and I convert my comment to an answer. (Questions answered in comments are a nuisance here on SE.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not say for which buffer you want to set the default directory.
If you want to do it for the (existing) shell buffer with name `*shell*` try the following shell command:

```sh
emacsclient -e '(with-current-buffer "*shell*" (setq default-directory "/home/joe/system-test/auth/"))`
```